# How to link a cell to a shape or picture in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

I am wondering if it's possible to link a cell to a shape or picture that when I click the cell, no matter where the shape/picture is within the workbook, it should locate it. This is a shared document with other people who can edit it through excel online. I'd like a method which won't cause problems and work on the online version as well.

What I've tried:

I named a cell -> "Update". Then I right-clicked a shape -> hyperlink -> location within the workbook -> and selected "Update". So when I clicked the shape, it took me to the cell I named "Update". What I actually wanted was the opposite that by clicking the cell I locate the shape. The problem is for me, I tried to name that shape, but it doesn't show up in the hyperlink options like with cells.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**To solve the issue you need a VBA (Macro):**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectShape1()

 Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Visible = True
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Oval 1").Select

End Sub

Sub SelectShape2()

 Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Smiley Face 1").Visible = True
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Smiley Face 1").Select

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Count = 1 Then

      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Call SelectShape1
      End If

      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
       Call SelectShape2
      End If
      End If

 End Sub
```

**Note:**

- Copy & Paste these Macro as Standard Module.
- You may have many Shapes across Sheets, so that I've used Cell `A1` & `A2` to Click to Select them.
- Insert Shapes in respective Sheets before you Click Cell `A1` or `A2` in `Sheet 1`.
- With above shown Macros  `Range("A1")`, `Range("A2")` & `.Shape("Oval 1")` & `.Shape("Smiley Face 1")` are editable.
- `Worksheet Change event` records Click on Cell `A1` & `A2`, then executes related Macro to select the Shape.
- You may extend Code to locate others Shapes, since I'v created Macro 
  for two only.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time to answer my question sir! Does Macro functions work on Excel online? Because I have a workbook that is shared with people to edit. I tried a method like giving the cell a name and right clicking it -> hyperlink, from there I could see the cell I named and I was able to select it. This worked if linking a cell to a cell, but not a shape.

Comment: @SunnyS-h, You will not be able to create macro with VBA in Excel Online, however you can open and edit VBA-enabled spreadsheets without removing or corrupting the VBA contained in the file.

For more information you may refer to the section ‘VBA and macro scripting’ in the link below:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/excel-online-service-description.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @SunnyS-h, since you are working with Excel Online  therefore my suggestion is better edit the question and add line at the end that, you need solution should work with Excel Online.